# PICkit 5 giving -109 error when programming PIC

Tags: pic, microchip, programming, mplabx, pickit

I have a PICkit 5 which I think is correctly connected to a PIC16lf18425. Whenever try to program it I get

> error -109

I just have a 0.1 uf electrolytic capacitor between GND and VDD and a 10k ohm resistor between VDD and MCLR. The rest is:

- TVPP to MCLR
- TVDD to VDD
- GND to VSS
- PGD to ICSPDAT
- PGC to ICSPCLK

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if [this](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/PICKit-5-debug-connection-fails-with-Transmission-on-endpoint-2-failed--err----109--on-a-Windows-PC) support article from Microchip fixes it.

Comment: @TomCarpenter ive tried dat article already

Comment: You may get better support on the [Microchip forum](https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000Bq43EAC/t391366).

Comment: @TomCarpenter smart